# motorcycle sputters and temporarily dies

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, carburetor, cdi

Recently, my motorcycle (2008 Ducati Hypermotard 1100) has been temporarily dying while riding it, usually on the lower RPMs of the lower gears.  I thought it was the heat, but today in the rain it was happening more in upper 2nd / 3rd.  It just sputters and then comes back to life.

What do you think this is? I've added some tags with my guesses. I'm about to take it on a long-ish trip.  Is this dangerous?

I recently had to replace the negative battery terminal lug after it snapped.  I just stripped, crimped, and electrical-taped it.  Could this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your battery repair could definitely have something to do with it. At low revs there could be vibration and movement.

I'd get that sorted first as it is the obvious weak point. If that doesn't sort it, then further diagnosis is required.

Comment: I would add that making sure the terminals are clean and have really good contact is a good first thing to check. Check the positive side as well as it could have been jostled or bumped when changing the other terminal.

Comment: I opened the seat and found out that the eye on ethe lug I attached was too big.  I attached a different lug and everything was fine.